# Error in objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter

Tags: java, oracle

I get error at while using `OracleTypes.Cursor`

```
performDiffProcedureName = "{call LOCO_PERFORM_DIFF_ALL_RLST_PR(?,?)}";

            objCallableStatement = null;
            objCallableStatement = connection
                    .prepareCall(performDiffProcedureName);

            LogUtil.logMessage("Inside perform diff others--"
                    + LCPartNumber1 + "--" + LCPartNumber2 + "--"
                    + performDiffProcedureName);
            objCallableStatement.setInt(1, Integer
                    .parseInt(LCPartNumber1));
            objCallableStatement.setInt(2, Integer
                    .parseInt(LCPartNumber2));
            objCallableStatement.execute();
            connection.commit();

            performDiffProcedureName = "{call PERFORM_DIFFREPORT_PR(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
            objCallableStatement = connection.prepareCall(performDiffProcedureName);

            objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

Comment: Hi guys,  am receiving error at OracleTypes.CURSOR as cann't find symbol, b4 am using 11g Oracle DB, now changes to 12c i added ojdbc7.jar .

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Comment: 1st Error at:    oracle.sql.BLOB myBlob = oracle.sql.BLOB
   .createTemporary(connection, false,    
                                                           oracle.sql.BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);

Comment: 2nd: cann't find symbol OracleTypes.CURSOR 
            objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            objCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);